# How to integrate Custom report to Hudson email and in Hudson UI?

Tags: maven, hudson, testng, soapui

I am generating custom report(HTML) for soapUi and I am using TestNG and Maven.
How do i generate Report?
 ->I manually create a Reports Folder and create HTML Report file after every run.(I am NOT
   using surefire report) i.e, I have added this action in setup and teardown method.

Mentioned below is my project overview.

Main Proj(Maven)
  | - src/main/java/tests/classes
  | - test-output(TestNG)
  | - Reports
       | - SampleReport.html

Now How to integrate with Hudson? I mean This report should be displayed in Hudson and sent as email report.

Answer (score 1):

There is a TestNG plugin for Jenkins that you can use to parse TestNG reults, ie.
TestNG XML report pattern: **/testng-results.xml
We are using it and this presents results in a very nice way in Jenkins.
Then, to email your html report, you can use Email-ext plugin. It will let you change email contents to HTML and attach your result, ie.
${FILE, path="target/surefire-reports/emailable-report.html"}

Hope this helps somewhat

Comment: Marcin, How I can embed a public domain link here? eg like: ${FILE, path="http://www.w3schools.com"}